# Docker is not recompiling upon changing anything in angular project in windows

Tags: angular, docker

I am trying to dockarize my angular app and for that i have created one Dockerfile. But whenever i tried to edit or update any component its not recompiling my angular app. here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
```

And during docker run here is the comand that i use.

```
docker run -it -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app -p 4200:4200 angular-docker-image
```

Any idea why its not wroking and what should i do now?

Comment: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --poll 1` did this help

Comment: Are you running on Windows ? If yes, there is a lot of problem with inotify (file changes notification system). You can use the @Adiii solution to correct the problem

Comment: ya i am using windows @martin-paucot

Comment: thank you @adii . its working now. I am so greatful to you.

Comment: @adiii you can add a answer and  i will surely accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Windows Family (Docker Toolbox) or Windows Linux Subsystem**

When running on Docker Toolbox or WLS, the file changement event system of Windows will not trigger any event in the VM (or Subsystem) so the watcher will not be informed.

Windows made an update in the Insider Program on the [build #14942](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes#build-14942) but it only works on the Windows notepad...

**Windows Professional**

If you are working on Windows Professional and using Docker For Windows, it's a [known issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/56#issuecomment-242135705).

---

**The workarounds is to use the polling feature of your file watcher. For Angular :**

`ng serve --poll <period_in_ms>`

Answer (score 2):

You can try with  `--poll`

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --poll 1
```

**poll**

> Enable and define the file watching poll time period in milliseconds.

https://angular.io/cli/serve