# mounted volumes are only partially appearing and empty using docker-compose on WSL

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Here is my docker-compose file (sorry for the images but the WSL terminal won't let me copy-paste indented text):

[image]

The intention being that `external_stuff` contains my mounts directory. When I look in the mounts directory I clearly see my drives:

[image]

However, when I run `docker-compose up` I only see a single folder ("c") as opposed to all of my drives, and when I navigate into that folder it appears empty:

[image]

I tried running `sudo -E docker-compose up` but that makes no difference.

What's going on here, and how do I fix it?

My system:

- Docker desktop version 2.1.0.5
- Windows build 1903 / OS Build 18362.476
- I think I'm running wsl 1 but I really have no idea. If I run `wsl -l` from a powershell it spits out a bunch of command line options.
- I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS directly from the "Ubuntu" app in windows.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
```

Comment: Some information is needed: Windows 10 version, wsl1 or wsl2, a minimal dockerfile to reproduce the issue, wsl distro name.

Comment: @Biswapriyo see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Desktop is running on a VM and you need to share your drives with it.
When running Docker Desktop through WSL, you will still need to share the drives you are using.

For this, you simply have to go into `Docker Desktop Settings > Shared Drives` and then allow sharing your drives.

Then you can work on Docker Desktop through WSL with linux commands, linux paths, etc.

> Disclaimer : WSL and Docker Desktop are really unstable, with sharing volumes, permissions, inotify events, etc. You can find more information about theses problems on the answer of this question : [Docker is not recompiling upon changing anything in angular project in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728042/docker-is-not-recompiling-upon-changing-anything-in-angular-project-in-windows/58730258#58730258)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried mounting a folder with only a single file in it, but it still appeared empty in my docker container. I am currently running docker desktop on the host.

Comment: Could you try to do the same thing by running your `docker-compose up` on windows (terminal or powershell) with the folder on disk C and changing the volume path with windows path (ex: `C:\Users\Example\Workspace`). Docker Desktop runs on a linux VM so you need to allow sharing your drives.

Comment: Well, if I run it from windows I get a message saying "Docker wants to access...", then if I click "Share It" nothing happens, it just hangs on "recreating..." indefinitely.

Comment: Share the driver in Docker Desktop settings > Shared Drives. Then try to run again `docker-compose up`

Comment: Do you have any firewall on your computer ?

Comment: Ok that seems to work, thanks for the workaround. I still don't quite understand why wsl fails though, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: No I don't have a firewall, at least not in addition to windows defender.

Comment: Now could you try by running it in WSL ? On the same driver (which is now shared) and using linux path

Comment: Ahh, that fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Perfect, I will edit my answer with the solution, feel free to mark as solved !